# trying to move app point of entry doesn't work (EXPO)

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I'm trying to create an index.js file in my expo app:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

let store = createStore(reducers,applyMiddleware(thunk))

const RNRedux = () => {
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);
```

I'm doing this because I need access to the store within my App.js file and I keep hitting this error

```
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.
```

I fixed the main file in the package.json as well but the error still remains. Any ideas/other workarounds to this issue? Would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I see there is a duplicate import at Provider. Can you remove one?

Comment: `RNRedux` doesn't return anything. It should return JSX. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 0):

I guess your app will contain Navigation folder. So just do in this way.

App.js

```
import store from './store'

const App = () => {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Store.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export default store;
```

Hope it give you idea